# Dynamically add DIVs to a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

So I have a text-based exploring game where the user can type the direction and go places and appropriate images come up and so on. I have, so far, created a world with boundaries.

What I want to do now is to add items that the user can interact with -- sword, map and so on. I know I can create a div using `document.createElement("div")` but then, how will I add it to the modal div ?  I mean, I can add it to the body by `document.appendChild()` but to a div ?

Also, How do I remove it ?

[image]

So the user types **inventory** and the modal shows up. When the user types **pick**, say on a sword, there should be a new div added to it the next time user types **inventory**

*Suggestions to improve the game are welcome*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have reference to your modal window stored somewhere in variable:

```
// modal_div contains reference to your modal
// or to particular element inside it
var modal_div = document.getElementById("my_modal");

// later you create new element and use appendChild to add it
var new_element = document.createElement("div");
modal_div.appendChild(new_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.after()`, `.append()`, `.before()`, `.remove()` and such to add, remove, replace elements on your page.

You can navigate the DOM quite easily with jQuery, check out their tutorials: http://try.jquery.com/

Exercises about traversing the DOM: http://try.jquery.com/levels/2/challenges/1